# How to extract words between two words of different line from a txt file?

Tags: python

I have a .txt file which contains few lines and I wanted to extract specific words from each line

**Example:

 the txt file contains**

> Part A: **12** 10*2 = 20
>   Part B: **6**  4*5 = 20
>   Part C: **5** 3*10 = 30

I wanted to extract 12 into a variable similarly 6 and 5 to different variables
(the 1st digits after the colon or the digits between two spaces after the colon) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a regular expression to pick the first number from each line (after the colon and space):

```
import re
with open("filename.txt") as file:   
    fileText = file.read()
x, y, z = [int(n) for n in re.findall(": (\d+)", fileText)]
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

Comment: can you also extract the "Part A", "Part B" ..... into variables using this method?

Comment: Yes, it would be even simpler given that the returned values are strings: `a,b,c = re.findall("(.*):",fileText)`

Comment: cool works well...... can we able to skip the <space> example if it starts with "Part A :" (has space after 'A') the output to return only 'Part A' something like if there is a space before ":" (colon) so n so... else so n so

Comment: Use "(.*) *:"  to allow any number of spaces between the last character and the colon.  You might also want to lookup the capabilities of regular expressions.  They are really useful when parsing text.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the text, split, extract and store in an array like this!

```
file=open("filename.txt","r+")    
fileText=file.read()
file.close()
linesArr=fileText.split('\n')
x=linesArr[0].split(': ')[1].split(' ')[0]
y=linesArr[1].split(': ')[1].split(' ')[0]
z=linesArr[2].split(': ')[1].split(' ')[0]
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

Comment: I wanted to initialize the numbers into variables like 12 -> x, 6 -> y, 5-> z

Comment: Edited. Check now!

Comment: great working.......... could you also tell get how the 1st word that is "part A" with this syntax : `x=linesArr[0].split(': ')[1].split(' ')[0]` can be obtained

Comment: Yes. linesArr[0].split(': ') splits your line into two parts with : and space in middle. So 0th index of this array is your 'Part A'. The 1st index is the text after partA, : and space. So we split it by spaces, and detect 0th index, which is the first number in this later part of string.

Comment: the above 'part' code is not giving expected answer. its resulting as ['Part A', '12 10 * 2 = 20']

Comment: Use linesArr[0].split(': ')[0] to access part.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each line of the file and `split` it by space (), and get the third element (`third element <=> index = 2`), which is the number you want:

```
numbers = []

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    numbers.append(int(line.split()[2]))

print(numbers) # ==> [12, 6, 5]
```

Comment: I wanted to initialize the numbers into variables like 12 -> x, 6 -> y, 5-> z